# Print not fully connected to edge of frame

Tags: pla

I tried printing this mesh sheet, but the mesh part doesn't connect with the edge on one side. I have no idea what would be causing this. Is it something with the model? Is there a setting I can change in my slicer? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

This is the model that I am using: [3D Printed Mesh Sheet](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:5214203)

I'm printing with PLA on a Voxelab Aquila printer, and using Cura as my slicer.

As you can see, the mesh is not connected to the edge of the print:

[image: Mesh not connected to fourth edge of frame]